# using functions: print vs return

Tags: python, function

What is correct way to use data from functions in **Python** scripts?

Using `print`, like:

```
var1 = 'This is var1'

def func1():
  print(var1)

func1()
```

Or - with `return`:

```
var1 = 'This is var1'

def func1(): 
  return var1

print(func1())
```

Both give same result:

```
$ ./func_var_print_return.py
This is var1
```

Comment: print doesn't return values from a function! In this sense neither your question nor your example makes sense! try `print func1()` vs `print func2()`. (where your 2nd func1 Is func2!) But in all honestly in your example it doesn't really matter, because var1 is a "global" variable and stays the same regardless of the functions involved!

Comment: @DonQuestion thanks for replay. This is just quik simple example, so - of course, here is no anything from IRL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `return` a value when the purpose of the function is to produce a value. This is so functions can use other functions. For example

```
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

def multiply(a,b):
    product = 0
    for i in range(b):
        product = add(product, a)   # Note I am calling the add function
    return product
```

Testing

```
>>> multiply(5,4)
20
```

Note that I used the `return` value from `add` within my `multiply` function. If I only printed the value from `add`, I would have been unable to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation. In general I would return it so you can print if you want but if you code changes at some point you can perform other operations with the value

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to return the value.

Think of unit tests -> How would you verify the value if it's not returned?
And as mentioned by "meto" before, if your code changes you can still perform other operations with the value.