# How to get only negative numbers from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make def get_neg(): so that get_neg(lst) returns "-1, -2, -3" when lst = [-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6]. I tried this code below, but I don't know how to get the result in 1 line.

```
def get_neg():
    for n in lst:
        if n < 0:
            print(str(n) + ',')
        else:
            pass
```

This way I get each numbers in a different row and a comma at the end. It has to be programmed with basic commands

Comment: Don't make your functions print, because that makes their usability very limited. Make a function that returns the result you want and then do with the result whatever you want (in your case, `print`)

Comment: It seems like your question is really how to print on one line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically

Comment: "It has to be programmed with basic commands" — return statement is basic enough?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160393/using-functions-print-vs-return

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehensions (Do not forget to give `lst` as an argument to the `get_neg` function):

```py
def get_neg(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x < 0]
```

##### Example

```
get_neg([-1,-2,4,5]) # [-1, -2]
get_neg([-15,-22,-4, 5, 0]) # [-15, -22, -4]
```